# sorting Datagrid to highlight rows

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, sorting, advanceddatagrid

I currently have an advanced Datagrid which I have customised to highlight rows based on a conditional statement. I need to now sort the datagrid based of a specified column and then highlight the top 20%. so far I can get the row index and change the row color but need to find a way to highlight the top 20% of the ints in the column named "COLUMN_1"

```
if(data.getItemAt(dataIndex)){
    var row:Object = data.getItemAt(dataIndex);

if(//conditional statement needed)
      {

 color=(dataIndex%2==0)?0xff0033:0x880000;
      }
```

Comment: You try use a ItemRenderer?

Comment: How would I do that? thanks

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959074/itemrenderer-contentbackgroundcolor

Comment: i dont think that is the best option for me, I have created a custom datagrid to highlight the appropriate rows, therefore I just need a condtional statement that will decide if a row is in the top 20% based on a column of integers. This conditional statement will be in the drawRowBackground function of the custom datagridwhich has extended advanceddatagrid

Comment: Ok I also believe that with itemRenderer Might do the same job, fast and simple transparent. The renderer could decide in the same way if it is painted or not based on the percentage of that column. And with a simple reference in each column of the grid you implement. Also depends on what you want to do.

Comment: but the problem is i havent been able to highlight the entire row from an item renderer, thats why i created a custom datagrid. My other problem is i dont know how to create the conditional statment to highlight the top 20% of values from the specified column when this column will most likely be unordered. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I do not quite understand your idea, what I understand, I see no resort but without a graphic example of what I need I can not do much. I hope someone understands and can help.